# Devices don't connect with Bluetooth

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, 22.04

I am facing a problem with the bluetooth on my 22.04.
A few days ago my earphones connected just fine, but now, seemingly overnight, they won't connect. When I click on the slide "Connection" it slides to on, but almost immediately jumps back to off. What should I do?
Hans

Comment: Try again: Remove the device and pair it again.

Comment: It doesn't work, I think that the issue is with Ubuntu, because it works on Windows (dual-boot).

Comment: Didi you disabled Fast Startup in Windows already? It's a must when dual-booting. Among other issues it can cause what you describe.

Comment: I have never heard of that

Comment: Now you have...

Comment: Kay I'll try now

Comment: Ok I did it, but it still doesn't work